# Using React Native Animated to fade in and out elements

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native animated feature.  I am hoping to use it to fade in and out elements on button press.  The below code works to fade in the element when the page loads, but the button to fade it out does not fade it out as I would expect.  Can someone explain what I am doing wrong.  Thank you.

```
class FadeComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
    }
    this.fadeOut = this.fadeOut.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim,    // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 1,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,       // 2000ms
      }
    ).start();                // Starts the animation
  }

  fadeOut(){
    this.setState({fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1)})
    Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,       // 2000ms
      }
    ).start();                // Starts the animation
  }

  render() {
    let { fadeAnim } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style = {{ backgroundColor: '#1a8cff', marginTop: 100 }}>

        <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
          {this.props.children}
          <View style = {{ backgroundColor: '#000000', height: 50, width: 50 }}>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.fadeOut} >
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', textDecorationLine: 'underline', marginTop: 10 }}>
          fade out
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Because function setState is asynchronous. This should fix your issue:

```
this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
  () => {
    Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
      this.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,       // 2000ms
      }
    ).start();
  })
```

Comment: That fixed it and makes complete sense.  Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps set it as the answer?

Comment: in your 4th line you have this.state into a function, and the value is not changed because you lose the original scope 'this' var
```var self = this;
this.setState({ fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(1) },
  () => {
    Animated.timing(          // Animate over time
      self.state.fadeAnim, // The animated value to drive
      {
        toValue: 0,           // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
        duration: 2000,       // 2000ms
      }
    ).start();
  })```